# Oracle SQL recursion to find first instance of non-null column value

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, hierarchical-data

I'll try and explain how the table is laid out so that what I need might be a bit more clear.

```
###############################################################
# cid # iid # child cid # child iid # target cid # target iid #
############################################################### 
# 112 # 1   # null      # null      # 116        # 1          #
# 112 # 2   # 112       # 1         # null       # null       #
# 112 # 3   # 112       # 1         # 116        # 2          #
# 112 # 4   # 112       # 1         # 100        # 3          #
# 112 # 101 # null      # null      # 116        # 101        #
# 112 # 102 # 112       # 101       # null       # null       #
# 112 # 103 # 112       # 101       # 116        # 102        #
# 112 # 201 # null      # null      # 116        # 201        #
# 112 # 202 # 112       # 201       # null       # null       #
# 112 # 203 # 112       # 201       # 116        # 202        #
# 112 # 301 # null      # null      # 116        # 301        #
# 112 # 302 # 112       # 301       # null       # null       #
# 112 # 302 # 112       # 301       # 116        # 302        #
```

Above there is a cut down representation of the table I'm trying to get data from. Sorry if the layout is a bit crap. Each row here is an object. Each of these objects can have child objects so for example, the first row has no child objects but is linked to the target object. Row two has a child object and isn't linked to a target object, however, it is linked back to row 1 via the child cid and iid which does have a target object. Row three is also linked to row one but it also has a target object so I don't actually want to go back to row one.

Other table

```
#########################################
# cid # iid # col1 # col2 # col3 # col4 #
#########################################
# 116 # 1   # a    # null # 16   # 1    #
# 116 # 2   # b    # 1    # 6    # null #
# 116 # 3   # n    # 1    # 11   # 2    #
# 116 # 101 # n    # 2    # 61   # 3    #
# 116 # 102 # b    # null # 161  # 101  #
# 116 # 201 # a    # 33   # 312  # 116  # 
# 116 # 202 # a    # 33   # 312  # 116  # 
# 116 # 301 # s    # 56   # 1321 # 33   #
# 116 # 302 # r    # 6    # 22   # 12   #
```

Resulting table

```
###########################################################################################
# cid # iid # child cid # child iid # target cid # target iid # col1 # col2 # col3 # col4 #
###########################################################################################
# 112 # 1   # null      # null      # 116        # 1          # a    # null # 16   # 1    #
# 112 # 2   # 112       # 1         # null       # null       # a    # null # 16   # 1    #
# 112 # 3   # 112       # 1         # 116        # 2          # b    # 1    # 6    # null #
# 112 # 4   # 112       # 1         # 100        # 3          # n    # 1    # 11   # 2    #
# 112 # 101 # null      # null      # 116        # 101        # n    # 2    # 61   # 3    #
# 112 # 102 # 112       # 101       # null       # null       # n    # 2    # 61   # 3    #
# 112 # 103 # 112       # 101       # 116        # 102        # b    # null # 161  # 101  #
# 112 # 201 # null      # null      # 116        # 201        # a    # 33   # 312  # 116  #
# 112 # 202 # 112       # 201       # null       # null       # a    # 33   # 312  # 116  #
# 112 # 203 # 112       # 201       # 116        # 202        # a    # 33   # 312  # 116  # 
# 112 # 301 # null      # null      # 116        # 301        # s    # 56   # 1321 # 33   #
# 112 # 302 # 112       # 301       # null       # null       # s    # 56   # 1321 # 33   #
# 112 # 302 # 112       # 301       # 116        # 302        # r    # 6    # 22   # 12   #
```

[Just to clarify, in the first table, target cid and iid relate to cid and iid in the other table im linking to it.]

Essentially what I need is to recursively go back through the table until a row has a target object reference.

If a row has both a child c/i id and a target c/i id i just want the target c/i id.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

I'm slowly reading through
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm but I'm finding it a bit confusing. I wouldn't exactly be an expert in the easier SQL queries so recursion is a bit over my head right now.

Thanks

EDIT: Added example of other table and outcome

Comment: what is the expected outcome for this data ?

Comment: basically, I'm trying to link another table to this one. The idea is that the target ids should match that of the other table. I need each row of the table above to have a reference to a target iid so i can link the relevant data from the other table to it.

Comment: show the two tables + the data and the expected result.

Comment: This is not a DB2 question, bad tagged.

Comment: added tables and removed DB2 tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know what exactly do you need, but
you could start with tihs statment

```
select cid, iid, level, connect_by_root(target_cid), connect_by_root(target_iid)
from tab
connect by    prior cid = child_cid
          AND prior iid = child_iid
          AND target_cid is null          
;
```

and then filtern the entries you need

```
select *
from 
(
select cid, iid, level, connect_by_root(target_cid) as target_cid, connect_by_root(target_iid) as target_iid
from tab
connect by    prior cid = child_cid
          AND prior iid = child_iid
          AND target_cid is null          
)
where target_cid is not null
;          

    CID IID TARGET_CID TARGET_IID
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    112 1     116         1
    112 2     116         1
    112 3     116         2
    112 4     100         3
    112 101   116         101
    112 102   116         101
    112 103   116         102
    112 201   116         201
    112 202   116         201
    112 203   116         202
    112 301   116         301
    112 302   116         301
    112 302   116         302
```

Comment: Great starting point, helped me solve my similar problem. As far as I can tell, instead of filtering (nested query and `where target_cid is not null`), it would be possible to write `start with target_cid is not null connect by ...` without a nested query to get only the not-null results for `target_cid` (but I only tested it on a very limited dataset)