# Recursively finding the next non-self, non-null value in a table using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, recursion, plsql, oracle11g

I have a data set composed of two elements: position numbers that represent a hierarchy of jobs, and people assigned to those position numbers. Each position number also has a parent position.

Not every position has a person appointed to it. Further, people can be assigned to more than one position (for example, a Sales Manager might also be appointed as the interim Regional Sales Manager).

What I'm trying to do is find the next non-self, non-null manager for a given person.

Below is an example of the data set. Let's call the table "positions":

```
Position  Title              Employee_ID     Name      Parent_Position

001       Salesperson            A           Mike            002
002       Sales Manager          B           Rob             003
003       Regional Sales Mgr     B           Rob             004
004       VP of Sales          [NULL]       [NULL]           005
005       Executive VP           C           Liz             006
006       CEO                    D           Annie          [NULL]
```

The output I'm trying to achieve is as follows (though additional columns are fine):

```
Employee_ID     Name     Manager_ID    Manager_Name

    A           Mike         B            Rob
    B           Rob          C            Liz
    C           Liz          D            Annie
    D           Annie      [NULL]        [NULL]
```

I have done a fair amount of playing around with CONNECT BY PRIOR over the last week and searching on here and via the general Googleverse. The closest I could find to this was the following example:

[Oracle SQL recursion to find first instance of non-null column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592421/oracle-sql-recursion-to-find-first-instance-of-non-null-column-value)

However, this data set is just different enough that I'm having trouble applying that answer to my specific problem because I'm essentially stripping out the position-to-position info to get person-to-person info instead.

My background is more in object-oriented programming than SQL, so my instinct is to write a function to handle this, but I'm not a DBA so I only have query access. I've read Oracle's CONNECT BY PRIOR documentation and when it comes to just traversing the position hierarchy I don't have any problems, but I'm stuck on how to get to just the person info based on the requirements (non-self non-null).

Note: this is my first post here. Please let me know if I should include further info or if I should clarify anything.

Comment: Please include some samples of what you have tried. Word descriptions just aren't enough.

Comment: How are you going to use this in real life? It seems the input would be an employee id; but the data set is not suitable for that. For example if you input employee id = B, where does the hierarchy begin?

Comment: Regarding samples--I'll try to upload some tomorrow. The data set is a bit complex and it's all proprietary/confidential stuff so I have to water it down to show an example, which will take some time.

Using this in real life:

I have a file feed of users going to a 3rd party software from our ERP. The ERP is all position-based. The 3rd party software is all user-based. As such, I need to send over a manager for each user rather than send over the position hierarchy. This is basically a sub-query that I'll be using to left outer join to the main user query, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

First get a list of all managers per employee. Use a recursive CTE for this. Then rank the records per employee_id, preferring non-null managers with a position as close as possible to the employee.

```
with cte(emp_pos, emp_id, mgr_pos, mgr_id, levl, parent_position) as
(
  select position as emp_pos, null as mgr_pos, null as mgr_id, 1 as levl, parent_position
  from positions 
  where employee_id is not null
  union all
  select
    cte.emp_pos, 
    p.position as mgr_pos, 
    p.employee_id as mgr_id, 
    cte.levl + 1 as levl, 
    p.parent_position
  from cte
  join positions p on p.position = cte.parent_position
)
select 
  emp_pos.employee_id,
  emp_pos.name, 
  mgr_pos.employee_id as manager_id,
  mgr_pos.name as manager_name
from
(
  select 
    cte.*,
    row_number() over (
      partition by cte.emp_pos
      order by case when cte.mgr_id is null then 2 else 1 end, cte.levl) as rn
  from cte
  where (cte.emp_pos <> cte.mgr_pos or cte.mgr_pos is null)
)  
join positions emp_pos on emp_pos.position = cte.emp_pos
left join positions mgr_pos on mgr_pos.position = cte.mgr_pos
where cte.rn = 1;
```

I know this looks complicated (and maybe there are even flaws in the query), but I can't think of a simpler query for this.

Comment: Thanks. I think I see what you're doing here, and that might do the trick. I'll give it a try tomorrow and let you know.